# Horizontal Overflow with slideDown() / slideUp()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the slideUp() / slideDown() to animate the revelation of a page element but have had trouble with a relatively positioned icon with a negative (outside the element) placement.  While these animations execute it sets overflow to hidden rendering my icon cut in half until the animation completes.

[The JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/edallison/h9gtzp6f/6/) illustrates my issue. I need the horizontal overflow of the blue box to be visible during the whole execution of the animation instead of magically appearing at the end.  I also need the vertical overflow to remain hidden.

I've tried amending,

```
$(this).parent().find("div:eq(0)").slideDown(1000).css("overflow-x", "visible");
```

but it seems to be ignored and using,

```
$(this).parent().find("div:eq(0)").slideDown(1000).css("overflow", "visible");
```

also makes the vertical overflow visible.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Just wrap your divs like : div.clickEvent inside other div.hide

```
<div class="hide"><div class="clickEvent"> 
... 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h9gtzp6f/37/

Comment: In the actual project I'm working on there are several parent elements above the div all with the same width specifications.  Wouldn't I have to wrap those parent elements too? I'm concerned this would lead to undesired side effects.

Comment: E. Allison the problem is not coming from any width. It's simple how the animation process is working. When you use the wrap solution really you are letting the browser to handle that width. So I understood you have a kind of reusable component so just need to wrap it into one more div, that's all.

Comment: Because the parent elements have the same set width, setting the width of the the container to 100% does not work because it inherits the parent elements width.  [See here](https://jsfiddle.net/edallison/h9gtzp6f/35/).

Comment: Sorry ma'am just updated https://jsfiddle.net/h9gtzp6f/37/ . That width was not required really so I deleted it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('.clickMe').toggle(function() {
    var div = $(this).parent().find("div:eq(0)").show();
    var parent = div.parent();
    var wrapper = $('<div>', {'class': 'hide wrapper', html: div});
    parent.append(wrapper);
    wrapper.slideDown({duration:1000, complete: function(){parent.append(div);wrapper.remove();}});
}, function() {
    var div = $(this).parent().find("div:eq(0)");
    var parent = div.parent();
    var wrapper = $('<div>', {'class': 'wrapper', html: div});
    parent.append(wrapper);
    wrapper.slideUp({duration:"fast", complete: function(){parent.append(div);wrapper.remove();div.hide()}});
});
```

Comment: It's the same than I already provided (wrapping solution :) )

Comment: Yeah, I started posting before your solution was there. I guess they are different approaches to the same solution and it can't hurt to have more options